# Could not load SWT library on macOS

Tags: java, eclipse

I'm new on Eclipse and I tried to make a plug-in project and I also have a java project called "HelloWorld", when I ran the java project as "Eclipse Application", it had such error.

```
WARNING: Using incubator modules: jdk.incubator.vector, jdk.incubator.foreign
!SESSION 2022-06-20 14:28:15.833 -----------------------------------------------
eclipse.buildId=4.24.0.I20220607-0700
java.version=17.0.3
java.vendor=Eclipse Adoptium
BootLoader constants: OS=macosx, ARCH=aarch64, WS=cocoa, NL=zh_CN_#Hans
Framework arguments:  -product org.eclipse.sdk.ide
Command-line arguments:  -product org.eclipse.sdk.ide -data /Users/peiqi/eclipse-workspace/../runtime-EclipseApplication -dev file:/Users/peiqi/eclipse-workspace/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.pde.core/Eclipse Application/dev.properties -os macosx -ws cocoa -arch aarch64 -consoleLog

!ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 4 0 2022-06-20 14:28:20.693
!MESSAGE Application error
!STACK 1
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Could not load SWT library. Reasons: 
    Can't load /Users/peiqi/eclipse-workspace/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.pde.core/Eclipse Application/org.eclipse.osgi/356/0/.cp/libswt-cocoa-4952r11.jnilib
    no swt-cocoa in java.library.path: /Users/peiqi/Library/Java/Extensions:/Library/Java/Extensions:/Network/Library/Java/Extensions:/System/Library/Java/Extensions:/usr/lib/java:.
    no swt in java.library.path: /Users/peiqi/Library/Java/Extensions:/Library/Java/Extensions:/Network/Library/Java/Extensions:/System/Library/Java/Extensions:/usr/lib/java:.
    Can't load library: /Users/peiqi/.swt/lib/macosx/x86_64/libswt-cocoa-4952r11.jnilib
    Can't load library: /Users/peiqi/.swt/lib/macosx/x86_64/libswt-cocoa.jnilib
    Can't load library: /Users/peiqi/.swt/lib/macosx/x86_64/libswt.jnilib
    Can't load library: /Users/peiqi/.swt/lib/macosx/x86_64/libswt-cocoa-4952r11.jnilib

    at org.eclipse.swt.internal.Library.loadLibrary(Library.java:346)
    at org.eclipse.swt.internal.Library.loadLibrary(Library.java:255)
    at org.eclipse.swt.internal.C.<clinit>(C.java:19)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.<clinit>(Display.java:108)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createDisplay(Workbench.java:726)
    at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createDisplay(PlatformUI.java:168)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.createDisplay(IDEApplication.java:182)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.start(IDEApplication.java:125)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:203)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:136)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:104)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:402)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:255)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:659)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:596)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1467)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.main(Main.java:1440)
An error has occurred. See the log file
/Users/peiqi/runtime-EclipseApplication/.metadata/.log.
```

I worked it on Mac M1
THX!

Comment: Is your main Eclipse install aarch64 or x86_64?